# Bang aliases don't work

Tags: git, msysgit, git-alias

I tried to add some bang aliases (say... !git stash pop). But those does not work.

```
[alias]
    pop = !git stash pop
```

This unfortunatelly does not work (please ignore the fact I can use it without the bang - I needed a command to test it. My alias is more complex).

```
$ git pop
fatal: 'stash' appears to be a git command, but we were not
able to execute it. Maybe git-stash is broken?
```

It works withouth the bang

```
[alias]
    pop = stash pop
```

As expected

```
$ git pop
No stash found.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The ! is a reserved word in some shells (like bash and zsh) for example !! calls the last command in the history. Could be that the problem?

Comment: It's a feature. @see https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Prune_all_your_stale_remote_branches

Comment: I tried your exact example on msysgit 1.8.0 and it worked fine for me (with the bang). Can you specify your version? Also, try running with GIT_TRACE=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I traced it down to having non-ascii username and spaces in path!

Spaces in path in windows did work for msysgit executables. But did not work for anything bash. You need to add quotes around it to work in bash. That broke msysgit. So I need to install git to non-spaced path. Then it couldn't find my SSH keys because of non-ascii  characters in my home dir /home/Tomáš -> was /home/Tom%45%64 or something like that. So I needed to rename my local user. That seems to solve the issue completly.